# Getting databinding to observe changes to live data for recycler view

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I've been stuck on this for hours. Huge respect to whoever can help me figure this out.

My view is not updating whenever I change my MutableLiveData.

In my workout app, I have a list of exercises: MutableLiveData> that are displayed using a recycler view. The recycler view holder is using databinding to display the individual exercises inside this ArrayList. Whenever I update the entire list (using setValue), I'm expecting my view to update.

owever, since my databinding xml doesn't actually reference the MutableLiveData>(), only the ExerciseEntity elements inside the list, I don't think it's observing any changes. Therefore it's not updating. I can't figure out how to make it update properly.

**SelectorActivity:**

```
class SelectorActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var mExerciseSelectAdapter: ExerciseSelectAdapter
private lateinit var mViewModel: SelectorViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selector)

    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SelectorViewModel::class.java)
    mExerciseSelectAdapter = ExerciseSelectAdapter(this, mViewModel)

    setupRecyclerView()
    loadExerciseList(intent.hasExtra("LOAD_FROM_DB"), resources)
}

private fun setupRecyclerView(){
    rv_select_exers.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rv_select_exers.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rv_select_exers.adapter = mExerciseSelectAdapter
}

private fun loadExerciseList(loadFromDB: Boolean, resources: Resources) {
    doAsync {
           val myDBExercises = loadExersFromDB()
           mViewModel.populateExerciseListFromDB(myDBExercises)
           mExerciseSelectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

}

**SelectorViewModel:**

```
class SelectorViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mExerciseList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ExerciseEntity>>()
    val exerciseList : LiveData<ArrayList<ExerciseEntity>>
        get() = mExerciseList

    init {
        mExerciseList.value = ArrayList()
    }

    fun populateExerciseListFromDB(myDBExercises: List<ExerciseEntity>) {
        // .... Load our exer list from DB ... //


        mExerciseList.value?.addAll(myDBExercises)
        // Use the "setValue" method to notify observers of change
        mExerciseList.value = mExerciseList.value
    }

    private fun updateRepsInExercise(exercise: ExerciseEntity, reps1: Int, reps2: Int, reps3: Int) {
        exercise.set1Reps = reps1
        exercise.set2Reps = reps2
        exercise.set3Reps = reps3

        // Force our livedata to detect a change
        // TODO: not doing anything after increment set, our view is not updating
        mExerciseList.value = mExerciseList.value
    }

    fun incrementSet(exercise: ExerciseEntity, smallIncrement: Boolean) {
            // ... Compute the new reps ... //
            updateRepsInExercise(exercise, numReps1, numReps2, numReps3)
    }
}
```

**ExerciseSelectAdapter:**

class ExerciseSelectAdapter(private val mLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
                            private val mViewModel: SelectorViewModel) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter() {
    private lateinit var mExerciseList: ArrayList

```
init {
    // Use this to avoid blinking of list when data is changed
    setHasStableIds(true)

    // Get a reference to our viewmodel's exercise list
    if (mViewModel.exerciseList.value != null ) mExerciseList = mViewModel.exerciseList.value!!
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExerciseSelectViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val dataBinding: ExerciseSelectBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.exercise_select, parent, false);
    dataBinding.setLifecycleOwner(mLifecycleOwner)
    return ExerciseSelectViewHolder(dataBinding, mLifecycleOwner, mViewModel)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExerciseSelectViewHolder, index: Int) {
    holder.bindExerciseSelectView(mExerciseList[index])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mExerciseList.size
}

// Use this to avoid blinking of list when data is changed
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return mExerciseList[position].exerciseNum.toLong()
}
```

}

**ExerciseSelectViewHolder:**

```
class ExerciseSelectViewHolder(private val mDataBinding: ExerciseSelectBinding,
                               private val mLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
                               private val mViewModel: SelectorViewModel):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mDataBinding.root){

    init {
        // Used to enable proper observation of LiveData
        mDataBinding.setLifecycleOwner(mLifecycleOwner)
    }

    fun bindExerciseSelectView(exerciseEntity: ExerciseEntity) {
        mDataBinding.exerciseEntity = exerciseEntity
        mDataBinding.viewModel = mViewModel
        mDataBinding.spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(mLifecycleOwner as Context,
                R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                exerciseEntity.allProgressions)
        // Forces the bindings to run immediately
        mDataBinding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

**activity_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.epsilon.startbodyweight.selectorActivity.SelectorActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_select_exers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**exercise_select.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>
        <data>
            <import type="android.view.View"/>
            <variable
                name="exerciseEntity"
                type="com.epsilon.startbodyweight.data.ExerciseEntity"/>
            <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="com.epsilon.startbodyweight.selectorActivity.SelectorViewModel"/>
            <variable
                name="spinnerAdapter"
                type="android.widget.ArrayAdapter" />
        </data>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_sel_exer"
                //... Styling stuff
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:adapter="@{spinnerAdapter}"
                android:selection="@{exerciseEntity.progressionNumber}"
                android:onItemSelected="@{(parent,view,position,id) -> viewModel.onItemSelectedSpinner(parent,position,exerciseEntity)}"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                //... Styling stuff
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.incrementSet(exerciseEntity, true)}"
                android:text="↑" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_sel_rep_1"
                // ... Styling stuff
                android:text="@{String.valueOf(exerciseEntity.set1Reps)}"
                android:visibility="@{!exerciseEntity.isTimedExercise ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_sel_rep_2"
                //... Styling stuff
                android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewModel.exerciseList)}"
                android:visibility="@{!exerciseEntity.isTimedExercise ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_sel_rep_3"
                //... Styling stuff
                android:text="@{String.valueOf(exerciseEntity.set3Reps)}"
                android:visibility="@{!exerciseEntity.isTimedExercise ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

Do I need to make the databinding observe changes to the MutableLiveData> when it's not actually using this list at all in the layout XML? I thought of making every member of the ArrayList as another mutable live data, like this: MutableLiveData>>, but that seems rather complicated...

**EDIT:** I've found a solution, it's pretty easy but not ideal. Still looking for suggestions.

Instead of binding the exerciseEntity directly to my data binding XML layout, instead I bind the position of the element in the list. Then in my xml, I access the element using the list and this index.

In exercise_select.xml, I've replaced

```
android:text="@{String.valueOf(exerciseEntity.set2Reps)}"
```

by

```
android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewModel.exerciseList[index].set2Reps)}"
```

This seems to convince the databinding to finally observe modifications to the ArrayList.

I am not satisfied, is there a more "best practices" way of doing this?

Comment: are you aware of `PagedListAdapter` which simplifies a lot `RecyclerView` related stuff (and also makes your app very fast when your data set is relatively big)? more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html)

Comment: I'm not aware of this, I'm still learning about this architecture. Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I'm gonna check it out. Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Comment: You can use android paging library for data pagination when you have large amount of data. You can check out [this sample](https://codingwithdhrumil.com/2020/04/exploring-android-jetpack-paging-library-using-kotlin.html) for MVVM + Pagination + Retrofit2 + Data Binding + Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem, but I know that databinding itself is not able to update the list of exercises in the adapter by itself, since databinding does not (and should not) have access to the adapter-instance in the layout-xml.

You should observe the changes to the list of exercises in the activity, and if the list changes, submit it to the adapter, so it can update the recyclerview:

```
class SelectorActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
// ...
private fun setupRecyclerView(){
    rv_select_exers.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rv_select_exers.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rv_select_exers.adapter = mExerciseSelectAdapter
    // observe changes to the list-liveData in the viewmodel
    mViewModel.exerciseList.observe(this) { exercises ->
        mExerciseSelectAdapter.submitList(exercises)
    }
// ...
private fun loadExerciseList(loadFromDB: Boolean, resources: Resources) {
    // I would advise to switch to kotlin-coroutines and move
    // db-loading to the viewModel into an viewModelScope-block
    // so the loading is cancelled when the app/activity is left by the user
    doAsync {
           val myDBExercises = loadExersFromDB()
           // I think doAsync (from Anko?) does not do its work on the
           // UI-thread, so switch to UI-thread before populating
           mViewModel.populateExerciseListFromDB(myDBExercises)
           // this notifyDataSetChanged is not needed anymore
           // because of the observe-call above
           // mExerciseSelectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: I just noticed you extend `RecyclerView.Adapter`, not `ListAdapter` (which would be best practice, but then you would also need a `DiffCallback` in the `ListAdapter`), so you don't have `adapter.submitList`, so update the list-instance in the adapter with a new set-method and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` as you already do.

Also what could be part of the update-problem: you remember a snapshot of the exercise-list in the adapter once during initialisation, and it is never updated from the adapters' perspective as far as I can tell (I think it may or may not be the same reference to the list anymore when you update the livedata-value, since the livedata may re-initialize its internal value-storage):

```
init {
    // ...

    // Get a reference to our viewmodel's exercise list
    if (mViewModel.exerciseList.value != null ) mExerciseList = mViewModel.exerciseList.value!!
}
```

This defeats the "loading the list from db and update the list" code.
Keep it simple and let only the observe-lambda change the list and access the `mViewModel.exerciseList` directly in the adapter instead of only the initial snapshot of it.

Regarding the populate-method, you can simply set the list to the livedata after loading from DB:

```
    fun populateExerciseListFromDB(myDBExercises: List<ExerciseEntity>) {
        // why load again? you load the list in loadExersFromDB and pass it in
        // .... Load our exer list from DB ... //

        // simply set the new list to the mutable livedata
        // Use the "setValue" method to notify observers of change
        mExerciseList.value = myDBExercises
    }
```